# Attribute is missing the android namespace prefix onClick

Tags: android

I am beginner to android dev,
I am getting subjected error in below code in last line. Please help

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" 
    andriod:onClick="sendMessage" 
    />
```

Thanks,

Himanshu

Comment: post the error log you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in `andriod:onClick`. Should be `android:onClick`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
andriod:onClick="sendMessage"
```

to

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved hours for me. :)